# Strange account suspension date

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I happened to notice an account
([link removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293213/280545))
 shown as suspended until the nonsensical date of “Mar 18 '92 at 16:28“? I am not asking why the account is suspended, but why the “until” date is 27 years in the past.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319634/380389) on the mother meta.

Comment: I've removed some comments which identified a particular suspended user.

Comment: [Duplicate on math.meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30516/11127).

Comment: @rob Could you clarify the reason for your edit? I don't see the connection between your action and the mother meta question that you link to - the latter question addresses attempts to discern the *reason* for a ban (which was not done here), not technical questions regarding its implementation.

Comment: @tparker You misread the other post. There should not a public Meta record of "user X is suspended until [date]," because (a) they can't participate in such a discussion, and (b) having such posts available after they return could make it harder for them to start clean. For consistency, we remove all such identifying information, without regard to speculation about whether the user is likely to return or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a '92 in the future, not in the past.

Suspensions longer than one year, or coordinated across sites, come from SE employees; the elected diamond moderators can only suspend up to a year.  That particular user was at some point suspended for 99999 days, until the year 2292.  The number of users network-wide with suspensions longer than ten years is very small, so there's no compelling reason to rewrite the date-display code to sometimes show a century digit.

Comment: Are you allowed to tell me/us the total number of suspended users w/ >10Y suspensions? Or is that not known to you?

Comment: @KyleKanos I decline to speculate.

Comment: @Kyle yeah I don't think we have access to that information through the mod tools. From the top answer on the meta.se version, "The number of legitimate users this would apply to can probably be counted on one hand", which is a guess I also find very plausible, but a guess nevertheless.